# Cashew flour in Kaju Katli

Tags: baking, indian-cuisine, cashews

All of the recipies for [Kaju Katli](https://www.indianhealthyrecipes.com/kaju-katli-kaju-barfi/) I've looked at says I should make my own cashew powder but I was wondering if I could substitute it with store bought cashew flour. I'm not sure what the difference is if there is any to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some nut flours have had oil removed from them (they're actually ground-up "oil cake", a byproduct of extracting nut oil). If your cashew powder doesn't say "defatted" or "oil cake" or "press cake" in the ingredients list, then no, there shouldn't be any difference.